# USB C ESD Device

Tags: usb-c

Is there a ESD Device that solves the problem of having to use vias or resistors to connect the 4 D lines of USB type C connectors? One that for example has 4 input for D lines that connects the D+/D- in the device with one output each for D+ and D-?

Comment: Which exact D lines you mean? The USB 2 lines, or USB 3 lines?

Comment: The D+/D- USB 2.0 lines

Comment: What you ask makes little sense. You need to protect only two USB2 lines. Not four. You do not need to protect 4 wires but two (even if they do go to 4 pins on the receptacle)

Comment: I understand, but I am asking if there is a device that has the 2 input for D-, and 2 input for D+ so you don't have to use stubs and vias to combine the lines exterior to the device. The block diagram would look like this. [img]https://i.imgur.com/Rj2DufB.jpg[/img]

Comment: They would still be stubs and you would likely need vias, but depends on connector pinout.

Answer (score 0):

The ESDS314DBVR is a good TVS diode that is built for USB 2.0. Basically you want to look for a TVS with a capacitance rating in the sub 10pf range, the lower the better.